# GooglePlay: как скопировать из открытого тестирования в релизную сборку?

Tags: google-play-console

Я закинул сборку в "открытое тестирование", предполагая потом переложить в выпуск.
Однака в списке "Скопировать" я вижу, что это невозможно, типа "для этой версии уже назначен проект". Как так, и как это обойти?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно перейти в раздел "Рабочая версия" и проверить наличие черновиков. Если есть черновик, то удалить его, и перевод в Рабочую версию станет активным.

У меня был именно такой случай.